# get date as type date in cq5

Tags: aem

I am using xtype datefield in my component.I want to get the value from my dialog as date not string.Is there any method to get the dialog value in any other type than string? As here I need Date.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. You can use the `get(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Class<T> type)` method of [ValueMap](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ValueMap.html#get%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) class to get a value and convert it to the type specified.

i.e. If you want the value of your property as Date, you can use the following syntax.

```
Date date = properties.get("date", Date.class);
```

You can also `get(java.lang.String name, T defaultValue)` method to return a default value in case the property doesn't exist in the repository. For Ex

```
Date date = properties.get("date", new Date());
Date date = properties.get("text", "default_text");
```

The default value is also used to define the type to convert the value to. i.e, it would return a String if the default value is String, or it would return a Date object if the default value is a Date object.

**NOTE:** The *properties* object is an instance of ValueMap

Comment: I used Date date = properties.get("date", new Date()); but Java new Date() is being printed. I am not able to fetch the "date" value from my component. Could any one help me out?

Comment: Is the name of your property "date" or is it something else?

Comment: yes its name only. I could get textfield xtype but not datefield xtype.

Comment: Can you provide the dialog config for your datefield?

Comment: jcr:primaryType: cq:Widget   xtype: datefield     name: ./date     fieldLabel: Enter date and the Type of xtype is String. SHould it be set to Date?? I get error when I select other type of xtype.

Comment: I notice this issue in AEM 6.1, the above code was working fine until 5.6.1. For a quick fix, you can use `{ "xtype": "datetime", "name": "./date", "hideTime": true}` and then the above code should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a default value as well. The default value you provide needs to be of the type you expect to get back.

```
Date date = properties.get("date", new Date());
```

http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ValueMap.html

Answer (score 1):

When we use datefield in cq5 dialog, its value gets saved as type 'Date' in CRX be default. While retrieving that property value from CRX on to a CQ page, we have to explicitly typecast the same to java.util.Date object as mentioned below.

```
java.util.Date date = properties.get("publishDate",java.util.Date.class);
```

Comment: When using xtype datefield its value stores as String in CRX. When using xtype datetime, it stores as Date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to revive this old question because I had the same issue and found, I think, a more elegant solution.

If you use the following configuration in your dialog for your field you will only get a date selection field but it will save as a date in CRX-DE:

```
xtype="datetime"
hideTime="{Boolean}true"
```